# Как написать счетчик попыток

Tags: java, android

Есть `EditText`, привязать к другому `EditText`.  Задать число попыток. Есть рандом число 0-9, и надо угадать число. Число вводим в `EditText`, если не совпало, то минус попытка.

Я думаю надо задать переменную, добавить в `EditText`:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_1:num.setText(String.valueOf(1));break;
        case R.id.btn_2:num.setText(String.valueOf(2));break;
        case R.id.btn_3:num.setText(String.valueOf(3));break;
        case R.id.btn_4:num.setText(String.valueOf(4));break;
        case R.id.btn_5:num.setText(String.valueOf(5));break;
        case R.id.btn_6:num.setText(String.valueOf(6));break;
        case R.id.btn_7:num.setText(String.valueOf(7));break;
        case R.id.btn_8:num.setText(String.valueOf(8));break;
        case R.id.btn_9:num.setText(String.valueOf(9));break;
        case R.id.btn_0:num.setText(String.valueOf(0));break;

    }

}

int i1;

public void ClickRestart (View v){
    Random r = new Random();
    i1 = (r.nextInt(10 ) + 0);
    less.setText("LESS");
    more.setText("MORE");
    win.setText("START");
    num.setText("");
   // tries.setText("3");
}

public void onClckPush(View v) {
   int num1;


    num1 = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());



    if (num1 == i1) {
        win.setText("You are WIN!");
        less.setText("");
        more.setText("");

    }else if (num1 > i1){
        less.setText("less");
        more.setText("");
        win.setText("TRY AGAIN!");
    //    TRY--;

    }else if (num1 < i1) {
        more.setText("more");
        less.setText("");
        win.setText("TRY AGAIN!");
      //  TRY--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final int TRIES_COUNT = 10;
int tries;
int number;

public void ClickRestart (View v){
    Random random = new Random();
    number = (random.nextInt(10));
    less.setText("LESS");
    more.setText("MORE");
    win.setText("START");
    num.setText("");
    tries = TRIES_COUNT;
    tries.setText(String.valueOf(tries));
}

public void onClckPush(View v) {
   if(tries > 0) {
       int guess;

       guess = Integer.parseInt(num.getText());

       if (guess == number) {
           win.setText("You are WIN!");
           less.setText("");
           more.setText("");
        } else if (guess > number) {
            less.setText("less");
            more.setText("");
            tryAgain();
        } else if (guess < number) {
            more.setText("more");
            less.setText("");
            tryAgain();
        }
    } else {
        win.setText("YOU LOSE!");
    }
}

public void tryAgain() {
     win.setText("TRY AGAIN!");
     tries--;
     tries.setText(tries);
}
```